# Optimize this ruby loop structure

Tags: ruby, loops

Given list of facts, test the fact `is_real?`, then return only passing_facts if the `speaker` attribute is not also stating alternative_facts.

```rb
passing_facts, alternative_facts = []
@facts.each do |fact|
  if fact.is_real?
    passing_facts << fact
  else
    alternative_facts << fact
  end
end

alternative_facts.each do |bad_fact|
  passing_facts = passing_facts.reject {|good_fact| good_fact.speaker == bad_fact.speaker }
end

return passing_facts
```

How do you re-arrange the loops/tests so data doesn't have to be access as many times.

Given data set has more `passing_facts` than `alternative_facts`

Comment: A simple example, with the expected result, would be helpful.

Comment: Your question title sounds more like a command than a question. PS this should probably be on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first 8 lines can be replaced by [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition).

This code iterates once over `@facts`, once over `alternative_facts` and once over `passing_facts`. It uses `Set` for faster lookups :

```
require 'set'

passing_facts, alternative_facts = @facts.partition(&:real?)

bad_speakers = Set.new(alternative_facts.map(&:speakers))

passing_facts.reject! do |fact|
  bad_speakers.include? fact.speaker
end

return passing_facts
```

The average complexity should be `O(n)`, compared to `O(n**2)` for your code and `O(n*log(n))` for the other answer.

Comment: Nice to see Set used for this purpose. Not only does it automatically remove duplicates, which makes things faster, but it has very fast look-up times as well.

Comment: Really like that you used `Set`, that didn't come to my mind when I was writing my answer. 

Just to note a common misconception about the `include?` method. It in fact iterates over the whole array. So your solution would be `O(n^2)`.

Source: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/2de1dbdffc99e21fc034241e581b85e4531097f4/array.c#L3962
Source: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#include-3F-method

Comment: @StankoKrtalićRusendić : `bad_speakers` is a set. So it uses [`Set#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-include-3F), which is O(1) on average.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't know that.

Comment: @StankoKrtalićRusendić : No problem. The score is now 1:1 for misguided comments ;)

Answer (score 3):

Depending if you count a sort as a loop this might suffice.

Since hash access is cheap we can say it's `O(1)` and sorting is `O(n*log(n))`. The following implementation would have `O(n + n*log(n))` which is the same as `O(n*log(n))`. That is less than `O(n + n^2)` ~ `O(n^2)` of your example.

This also meant that the data is accessed fewer times than in your example.

```
sorted_facts = @facts.sort_by(:real?).reverse!
author_invalidity = {}

sorted_facts.select do |fact|
  author_invalidity[fact.speaker] ||= !fact.real?
  fact.real? && !author_invalidity[fact.speaker]
end
```

A quick explanation of the idea.

We try to build a hash map of author validity to remove the nested loop from your example. By sorting the facts by truthfulness, so that the false ones come first, we can guarantee that by the time we iterate over the first true fact we have all the invalid authors in our hash map. Then by checking the hash and the fact we can build a list of valid facts in the same iteration we build the hash.

Note that the `author_invalidity` and double `!` are confusing but required in order to utilize `||=`. If instead `author_validity` would be stored (e.g. `author_validity[fact.speaker] ||= fact.real?`) then the check would always return `true` after the first valid author is processed. Therefore the logic has to be negative. As outlined in other answers, instead of a `Hash` a `Set` can be utilized. Then the logic would be positive.

Hope this gets you thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you write it as follows.

```
class Fact
  def initialize (fact)
     @fact = fact
  end
  def fact
    @fact[:fact]
  end
  def is_real?
     @fact[:real]
  end
  def speaker
     @fact[:speaker]
  end
end
```

Create some instances.

```
facts = [["grass is green", true, "Bob"], ["bears are orange", false, "Sue"],
         ["cats say 'woof'", false, "Bob"], ["dogs are delightful", true, "Hal"]].
          map { |f,t,s| Fact.new(fact: f, real: t, speaker: s) }
  #=> [#<Fact:0x007fd363e4bcc0 @fact=
  #      {:fact=>"grass is green", :real=>true, :speaker=>"Bob"}>,
  #    #<Fact:0x007fd363e4bc20 @fact=
  #      {:fact=>"bears are orange", :real=>false, :speaker=>"Sue"}>,
  #    #<Fact:0x007fd363e4bb80 @fact=
  #      {:fact=>"cats say 'woof'", :real=>false, :speaker=>"Bob"}>,
  #    #<Fact:0x007fd363e4bae0 @fact=
  #      {:fact=>"dogs are delightful", :real=>true, :speaker=>"Sue"}>
  #   ]
```

Partition `facts` into `passing_facts` and `alternative_facts`.

```
passing_facts, alternative_facts = facts.partition(&:is_real?)
  #=> [[#<Fact:0x007fd363e4bcc0 @fact=
  #       {:fact=>"grass is green", :real=>true, :speaker=>"Bob"}>,
  #     #<Fact:0x007fd363e4bae0 @fact=
  #       {:fact=>"dogs are delightful", :real=>true, :speaker=>"Hal"}>
  #    ],
  #    [#<Fact:0x007fd363e4bc20 @fact=
  #       {:fact=>"bears are orange", :real=>false, :speaker=>"Sue"}>,
  #     #<Fact:0x007fd363e4bb80 @fact=
  #       {:fact=>"cats say 'woof'", :real=>false, :speaker=>"Bob"}>
  #    ]
  #   ] 
passing_facts
  #=> [#<Fact:0x007fd363e4bcc0 @fact=
  #      {:fact=>"grass is green", :real=>true, :speaker=>"Bob"}>,
  #    #<Fact:0x007fd363e4bae0 @fact=
  #      {:fact=>"dogs are delightful", :real=>true, :speaker=>"Hal"}>
  #   ]
alternative_facts
  #   [#<Fact:0x007fd363e4bc20 @fact=
  #      {:fact=>"bears are orange", :real=>false, :speaker=>"Sue"}>,
  #    #<Fact:0x007fd363e4bb80 @fact=
  #      {:fact=>"cats say 'woof'", :real=>false, :speaker=>"Bob"}>
  #   ]
```

Compile list of speakers for `alternative_facts`.

```
alternative_speakers = alternative_facts.map { |f| f.speaker }
  #=> ["Sue", "Bob"]
```

Reject elements of `passing_facts` for which the value of the key `:speaker` is a member of `alternative_speakers`, then map those remaining to the name of the fact.

```
passing_facts.reject { |f| alternative_speakers.include?(f.speaker) }.
              map { |f| f.fact }
  #=> ["dogs are delightful"]
```

Note

```
passing_facts.reject { |f| alternative_speakers.include?(f.speaker) }
  #=> [#<Fact:0x007fd364a38e70 @fact=
  #     {:fact=>"dogs are delightful", :real=>true, :speaker=>"Hal"}>
  #   ]
```

If there are large number of "facts", efficiency could be improved by adding `require 'set'` and tack `.to_set` to the end of the expression that computes `facts`.